# Unable to install sonata/ecommerse on Symfony 4.1

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, sonata-admin, sonata

Unable to install sonata/ecommerse on Symfony 4.1

```
composer require sonata-project/ecommerce:dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 6.0.x-dev requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 6.0.1 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 6.0.0 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 5.0.3 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 5.0.2 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 5.0.1 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 5.0.0 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 4.0.6 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.2|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 4.0.5 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.2|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 4.0.4 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.2|^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 4.0.3 requires symfony/dependency-injection ~2.2|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 4.0.2 requires symfony/dependency-injection ~2.2|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 4.0.1 requires symfony/dependency-injection ~2.2|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
- egeloen/ckeditor-bundle 4.0.0 requires symfony/dependency-injection ~2.2|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
- sonata-project/ecommerce dev-master requires sonata-project/formatter-bundle ^3.4 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/formatter-bundle[3.4.0, 3.4.1,     3.5.0, 3.x-dev].
- sonata-project/formatter-bundle 3.4.0 requires egeloen/ckeditor-bundle ^4.0 || ^5.0 -> satisfiable by egeloen/ckeditor-bundle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3].
- sonata-project/formatter-bundle 3.4.1 requires egeloen/ckeditor-bundle ^4.0 || ^5.0 -> satisfiable by egeloen/ckeditor-bundle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3].
- sonata-project/formatter-bundle 3.5.0 requires egeloen/ckeditor-bundle ^4.0 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 -> satisfiable by egeloen/ckeditor-bundle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.x-dev].
- sonata-project/formatter-bundle 3.x-dev requires egeloen/ckeditor-bundle ^4.0 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 -> satisfiable by egeloen/ckeditor-bundle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.x-dev].
- Installation request for sonata-project/ecommerce dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/ecommerce[dev-master].

Potential causes:

A typo in the package name
The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
    It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Can you please show the contents of your `composer.json` file and the output of `composer show`?

Answer (score 0):

@xabbuh
**composer.json**

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.40",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "^2.4",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.6",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.5",
    "sonata-project/notification-orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "sonata-project/page-bundle": "^3.9",
    "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "^2.6",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.2",
    "symfony/asset": "*",
    "symfony/console": "*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/form": "*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/validator": "*",
    "symfony/web-link": "*",
    "symfony/yaml": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "*"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": true,
        "require": "4.1.*"
    }
}
```

`composer show`

`cocur/slugify                            v3.1    Converts a string into a slug.
doctrine/annotations                     v1.6.0  Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                           v1.8.0  Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                     v1.5.0  Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                          v2.9.0  Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                            v2.8.0  Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle                 1.9.1   Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle           1.3.3   Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle      v1.3.1  Symfony DoctrineMigrationsBundle
doctrine/event-manager                   v1.0.0  Doctrine Event Manager component
doctrine/inflector                       v1.3.0  Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                    1.1.0   A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                           v1.0.1  Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/migrations                      v1.8.1  Database Schema migrations using Doctrine DBAL
doctrine/orm                             v2.6.2  Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
doctrine/persistence                     v1.0.1  Doctrine Persistence abstractions.
doctrine/reflection                      v1.0.0  Doctrine Reflection component
easycorp/easy-log-handler                v1.0.7  A handler for Monolog that optimizes log messages to be processed by humans instead of software. Improve your productivity with logs that are easy to understand.
egulias/email-validator                  2.1.6   A library for validating emails against several RFCs
facebook/webdriver                       1.6.0   A PHP client for Selenium WebDriver
fig/link-util                            1.0.0   Common utility implementations for HTTP links
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle             v2.1.2  Symfony FOSUserBundle
jdorn/sql-formatter                      v1.2.17 a PHP SQL highlighting library
knplabs/knp-menu                         2.3.0   An object oriented menu library
knplabs/knp-menu-bundle                  v2.2.1  This bundle provides an integration of the KnpMenu library
monolog/monolog                          1.23.0  Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
nikic/php-parser                         v4.1.0  A PHP parser written in PHP
ocramius/package-versions                1.3.0   Composer plugin that provides efficient querying for installed package versions (no runtime IO)
ocramius/proxy-manager                   2.1.1   A library providing utilities to generate, instantiate and generally operate with Object Proxies
phpdocumentor/reflection-common          1.0.1   Common reflection classes used by phpdocumentor to reflect the code structure
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock        4.3.0   With this component, a library can provide support for annotations via DocBlocks or otherwise retrieve information that is embedded in a DocBlock.
phpdocumentor/type-resolver              0.4.0

psr/cache                                1.0.1   Common interface for caching libraries
psr/container                            1.0.0   Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/link                                 1.0.0   Common interfaces for HTTP links
psr/log                                  1.0.2   Common interface for logging libraries
psr/simple-cache                         1.0.1   Common interfaces for simple caching
sensio/framework-extra-bundle            v5.2.2  This bundle provides a way to configure your controllers with annotations
sonata-project/admin-bundle              3.40.2  The missing Symfony Admin Generator
sonata-project/block-bundle              3.12.1  Symfony SonataBlockBundle
sonata-project/cache                     1.1.1   Cache library
sonata-project/cache-bundle              2.4.2   This bundle provides caching services
sonata-project/core-bundle               3.11.2  Symfony SonataCoreBundle
sonata-project/datagrid-bundle           2.4.0   Symfony SonataDatagridBundle
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions       1.1.0   Doctrine2 behavioral extensions
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.6.3   Symfony Sonata / Integrate Doctrine ORM into the SonataAdminBundle
sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle       2.5.0   Symfony SonataEasyExtendsBundle
sonata-project/exporter                  1.9.1   Lightweight Exporter library
sonata-project/notification-bundle       3.5.1   Symfony SonataNotificationBundle
sonata-project/notification-orm-pack     1.0.0   A pack for SonataNotificationBundle with ORM support
sonata-project/page-bundle               3.9.0   This bundle provides a Site and Page management through container and block services
sonata-project/seo-bundle                2.6.1   Symfony SonataSeoBundle
sonata-project/user-bundle               4.2.3   Symfony SonataUserBundle
swiftmailer/swiftmailer                  v6.1.3  Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony-cmf/routing                      2.1.0   Extends the Symfony routing component for dynamic routes and chaining several routers
symfony-cmf/routing-bundle               2.1.1   Symfony RoutingBundle
symfony/asset                            v4.1.6  Symfony Asset Component
symfony/browser-kit                      v4.1.6  Symfony BrowserKit Component
symfony/cache                            v4.1.6  Symfony Cache component with PSR-6, PSR-16, and tags
symfony/config                           v4.1.6  Symfony Config Component
symfony/console                          v4.1.6  Symfony Console Component
symfony/css-selector                     v4.1.6  Symfony CssSelector Component
symfony/debug                            v4.1.6  Symfony Debug Component
symfony/debug-bundle                     v4.1.6  Symfony DebugBundle
symfony/debug-pack                       v1.0.6  A debug pack for Symfony projects
symfony/dependency-injection             v4.1.6  Symfony DependencyInjection Component
symfony/doctrine-bridge                  v4.1.6  Symfony Doctrine Bridge
symfony/dom-crawler                      v4.1.6  Symfony DomCrawler Component
symfony/dotenv                           v4.1.6  Registers environment variables from a .env file
symfony/event-dispatcher                 v4.1.6  Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/expression-language              v4.1.6  Symfony ExpressionLanguage Component
symfony/filesystem                       v4.1.6  Symfony Filesystem Component
symfony/finder                           v4.1.6  Symfony Finder Component
symfony/flex                             v1.1.1  Composer plugin for Symfony
symfony/form                             v4.1.6  Symfony Form Component
symfony/framework-bundle                 v4.1.6  Symfony FrameworkBundle
symfony/http-foundation                  v4.1.6  Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                      v4.1.6  Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/inflector                        v4.1.6  Symfony Inflector Component
symfony/intl                             v4.1.6  A PHP replacement layer for the C intl extension that includes additional data from the ICU library.
symfony/maker-bundle                     v1.8.0  Symfony Maker helps you create empty commands, controllers, form classes, tests and more so you can forget about writing boilerplate code.
symfony/monolog-bridge                   v4.1.6  Symfony Monolog Bridge
symfony/monolog-bundle                   v3.3.0  Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/options-resolver                 v4.1.6  Symfony OptionsResolver Component
symfony/orm-pack                         v1.0.5  A pack for the Doctrine ORM
symfony/panther                          v0.2.0  A browser testing and web scraping library for PHP and Symfony.
symfony/phpunit-bridge                   v4.1.6  Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu                v1.10.0 Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-related data and classes
symfony/polyfill-mbstring                v1.10.0 Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php72                   v1.10.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.2+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/process                          v4.1.6  Symfony Process Component
symfony/profiler-pack                    v1.0.3  A pack for the Symfony web profiler
symfony/property-access                  v4.1.6  Symfony PropertyAccess Component
symfony/property-info                    v4.1.6  Symfony Property Info Component
symfony/routing                          v4.1.6  Symfony Routing Component
symfony/security                         v4.1.6  Symfony Security Component
symfony/security-acl                     v3.0.1  Symfony Security Component - ACL (Access Control List)
symfony/security-bundle                  v4.1.6  Symfony SecurityBundle
symfony/serializer                       v4.1.6  Symfony Serializer Component
symfony/serializer-pack                  v1.0.1  A pack for the Symfony serializer
symfony/stopwatch                        v4.1.6  Symfony Stopwatch Component
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle               v3.2.4  Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/templating                       v4.1.6  Symfony Templating Component
symfony/test-pack                        v1.0.4  A pack for functional and end-to-end testing within a Symfony app
symfony/translation                      v4.1.6  Symfony Translation Component
symfony/twig-bridge                      v4.1.6  Symfony Twig Bridge
symfony/twig-bundle                      v4.1.6  Symfony TwigBundle
symfony/validator                        v4.1.6  Symfony Validator Component
symfony/var-dumper                       v4.1.6  Symfony mechanism for exploring and dumping PHP variables
symfony/web-link                         v4.1.6  Symfony WebLink Component
symfony/web-profiler-bundle              v4.1.6  Symfony WebProfilerBundle
symfony/web-server-bundle                v4.1.6  Symfony WebServerBundle
symfony/yaml                             v4.1.6  Symfony Yaml Component
twig/extensions                          v1.5.2  Common additional features for Twig that do not directly belong in core
twig/twig                                v2.5.0  Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
webmozart/assert                         1.3.0   Assertions to validate method input/output with nice error messages.
zendframework/zend-code                  3.3.1   provides facilities to generate arbitrary code using an object oriented interface
zendframework/zend-eventmanager          3.2.1   Trigger and listen to events within a PHP application
zendframework/zenddiagnostics            v1.3.1  A set of components for performing diagnostic tests in PHP applications`